# How can I connect and extend multiple EXTERNAL MONITORS to a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon

Tags: multiple-monitors

I know the laptop "Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th gen" has 1 HDMI port and a USB C port, is there a way to have 3 external monitors using extend (no duplicate screens)?

I bought a USB C Docking Station with HDMI and VGA, and I expected to connect 2 monitors to it and be able to extend the screen, however, the PC recognized them as 1, so the screens were duplicated, I want to be able to have different things displayed in each monitor.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences in Docking stations.
At first you have to be sure you bought docking station, and not a hub.

If you are sure you have docking station, it should be labeled with Thunderbolt 3. If it is, it should be able to do 2 4K monitors. Otherwise it can be hub/not thunderbolt dock/... (many producers name it differently).
Best practise is to look if it have mentiond support of 2 separate monitors in product description.

And Lenovo also have official dock called "ThinkPad Pro Dock", which should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by buying a [USB to HDMI Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XQHW8RT) and installing the driver [MSDisplay_MultiDev_v1.0.1.4(1)](https://mega.nz/folder/P8EXmaqa#1Awgaqr1StDmnxbnkKvYxw) from MEGA.

The quality of the image is not the best, but is what I wanted. Now I have an external monitor connected the HDMI port, another connected to the HDMI port of the USB C Docking Station, and another connected to the HDMI of the USB to HDMI Adapter.

Note: I posted this because I googled for hours and read many things, even things like the Lenovo ThinkPad doesn't support 3 external monitors.